# ASP.NET Repeater FindControl not working for Label, but works for Textbox

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

I'm facing issues trying to get controls from my repeater. I have one label and one textbox. The label is giving me a null reference error, however the textbox is working.

**Markup:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="PalletsRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="PalletsRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px;">
            <asp:Label lbl="lblPalletId" Text='<%#"Pallet "+Eval("PALLETID")%>' runat="server" />
            <asp:Label Text=", Qty = " CssClass="field-label-blue" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPalletItemQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ITEMQTY") %>' step="1" type="number" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
foreach (RepeaterItem repeaterRow in PalletsRepeater.Items)
{
    // This fails.
    string palletId = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)repeaterRow.FindControl("lblPalletId")).Text;
    // This works.
    string palletItemQty = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)repeaterRow.FindControl("txtPalletItemQty")).Text;
}
```

I have researched this on Stack Overflow and most answers involve using the OnItemDatabound event, but when I tried to implement those answers, it still comes back null for the label. Personally I don't understand the suggestions as far as using the OnItemDatabound event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<asp:Label lbl="lblPalletId" Text='<%#"Pallet "+Eval("PALLETID")%>' runat="server" />
```

Into

```
<asp:Label id="lblPalletId" Text='<%#"Pallet "+Eval("PALLETID")%>' runat="server" />
```

You cannot find it because it has no ID

Comment: Good God. I knew I would be embarrassed to find out the solution to my problem. Oh well, thank you for this!